# BigQuery quota limits from query table append apply or not?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

In my C# app I use a [BigQueryClient.CreateQueryJobAsync](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClient.html#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryClient_CreateQueryJobAsync_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryParameter__Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_QueryOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) to regularly append to a partitioned table `table1`. Currently this is happening only up to a 50-100 per day.

```
await BqClient.CreateQueryJobAsync(
    ...,
    new QueryOptions
    {
        DestinationTable = "table1",
        WriteDisposition = WriteDisposition.WriteAppend
    })
```

I understand that Big Query has many limits and these are usually well documented. But for this particular scenario I am not sure if the limits apply or not. The [quotas page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs) says there are "*1,000 updates per table per day*" **but** the documentation also explicitly lists which operations are affected by quota. Assuming there is an explicit list there must also be a list of "everything else" where the quota does not apply. For instance, "classic UI" is under the quota which should imply that the "new UI" **is not**. Similarly, the page states that [jobs.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) API is affected by quota but since I am using the official C# driver, it leaves me wondering as to whether this applies to my scenario or not.

Apparently, I could write a script to try to do the append operation 1001 times in 24 hours and see whether I hit the quota but I wish I could simply read this from documentation and understand without any ambiguity.

Does anyone know from first-hand experience how this actually works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery C# library internally uses jobs.query API, so the limit/quota applies in your case.

One more thing to be aware of is, since you're writing to a partitioned table, below quota also applies:

> **Maximum number of partition modifications per day per table — 5,000**
>
> You are limited to a total of 5,000 partition modifications per day
>   for a partitioned table. A partition can be modified by using an
>   operation that appends to or overwrites data in the partition.
>   Operations that modify partitions include: a load job, a query that
>   writes results to a partition, or a DML statement (INSERT, DELETE,
>   UPDATE, or MERGE) that modifies data in a partition.
>
> More than one partition may be affected by a single job. For example,
>   a DML statement can update data in multiple partitions (for both
>   ingestion-time and partitioned tables). Query jobs and load jobs can
>   also write to multiple partitions but only for partitioned tables.
>   BigQuery uses the number of partitions affected by a job when
>   determining how much of the quota the job consumes. Streaming inserts
>   do not affect this quota.

Comment: I am guessing `UploadJsonAsync` uses the streaming API.

Comment: `UploadJsonAsync` is a [load job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs), more specifically a [loading data from local](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local) job.

Comment: Thank you. So how does one do the steaming then?

Comment: It is called [InsertRows()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples)